# Regex: match only outside parenthesis (so that the text isn't split within parenthesis)?

Tags: python, regex

I have a target string which looks like this:

```
"foo (foo, foofoo), bar (foobar), foo, bar (barbar, foo), bar, foo"
```

and I want:

```
["foo (foo, foofoo)", "bar (foobar)", "foo", "bar (barbar, foo)", "bar", "foo"]
```

by splitting the target at `", "` *only outside the parenthesis*. What is the regex to match the commas outside the parenthesis? In my case, nested parenthesis do not appear and I don't have to consider them.

I personally use Python but any language example is fine.

Comment: In general, there is no regex which can handle this, because the parentheses could be nested to an arbitrary depth.  I think you might need to use a parser to handle the general problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
,(?![^(]*\))
```

You can use this to split.See demo.This holds true as u said there are no nested `()`.

https://regex101.com/r/wV5bD0/1

Comment: Thank you, genius. I took so long to understand haha.

Comment: Perfect, I've found numerous other answers on other threads which didn't work for Swift. This is the first answer that works for Swift Regex :)

Comment: This worked like a charm @vks. I needed to match text in a string that was not inside brackets e.g. "matched str [not matched]" and used a variation of your answer with `\w+(?![^\[]*\])`.

Comment: Thank you! I've been looking for a solution for 2 days because I'm really noob in regex. You save my day!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to extract the matches.  Assuming there are no nested `()`

```
(\w+(?: \([^\)]*\))?)
```

https://www.regex101.com/r/gR6jF1/1