# How to convert a String into a List using spark function PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am fetching a column from a Dataframe. The column is of `string` type.

`x = "[{somevalues, id:1, name:'xyz'}, {address:Some Value}, {somevalue}]"` & so on..

The data is stored as a string. It can be easily represented as a list.
I want the output to be:

```
LIST of [
{somevalues, id:1, name:'xyz'}, 
{address:Some Value}, 
{somevalue}
]
```

How can I achieve this using Spark's API? I know that with Python I can use the `eval(x)` function and it will return the list or I can use the `x.split()` function, which will also return a list. However, in this approach, it needs to iterate for each record.

Also, I want to use `mapPartition`; that is the reason why I need my string column to be in a list so that I can pass it to `mapPartition`.

Is there an efficient way where I can also convert my string data using spark API or would `mapPartitions` be even better as I will be looping every partition rather than every record?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regexp_replace to remove the square brackets and then split on the comma. At first, I'd thought you need to do something special to avoid splitting on the commas within the curly brackets. But it seems spark sql automatically avoids that. For example, the following query in Zeppelin

```
%sql
select split(regexp_replace("[{somevalues, id:1, name:'xyz'}, {address:Some Value}, {somevalue}]",  "[\\[\\] ]", ""), ",")
```

gives me

```
WrappedArray({somevalues, id:1, name:'xyz'}, {address:SomeValue}, {somevalue})
```

which is what you want.

You can use withColumn to add a column in this way if you're working with dataframes. And for some reason, if the comma within the curly brackets is being split on, you can do more regex-foo as in this post - [Regex: match only outside parenthesis (so that the text isn't split within parenthesis)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565349/regex-match-only-outside-parenthesis-so-that-the-text-isnt-split-within-paren).

Hope that makes sense. I'm not sure if you're using dataframes, but they're recommended over the lower level RDD api.

Comment: i don't want with Dataframes as later i need to do processing on RDD. I am using Python so can't use Datasets

Comment: @AJm, converting the dataframe to rdd is quite simple just call .rdd

Comment: Does not work . Gives error sql() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given). As i have replaced "[{somevalues, id:1, name:'xyz'}, {address:Some Value}, {somevalue}]" --> with the column name

Comment: @AJm, can you update the question with what you've tried and the detailed error message?

Comment: df = spark.sql("select split(regexp_replace(column_name,  ""[\\[\\] ]"", ""), ",") from table_1 ") ; 

df.show(10)

Comment: Also i looked the example >>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('100-200',)], ['str'])
>>> df.select(regexp_replace('str', '(\d+)', '--').alias('d')).collect()
[Row(d=u'-----')]

But i don't understand why this [Row(d=u'----')]  This i don't need i just need the Curly brackets and the values inside it

Answer (score 0):

**If you don't want to go to `dataframes`** then you can use *regex replace* and *split* functions on the *rdd* data you created .

If you have data as

```
x = "[{somevalues, id:1, name:'xyz'}, {address:Some Value}, {somevalue}]"
```

Then you can create *rdd* and use *regex replace* and *split* functions as

```
import re
rdd = sc.parallelize([x]).flatMap(lambda x: re.sub("},\\{", "};&;{", re.sub("[\\[\\]\s+]", "", x)).split(";&;"))
```

`flatMap` is used so that *the splitted data comes in separate rows* as

```
{somevalues,id:1,name:'xyz'}
{address:SomeValue}
{somevalue}
```

I hope the answer is helpful

**Note** : If you want the solution in `dataframe` way then you can get ideas from my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49204947/5880706)