# how to match text NOT in parentheses and quotes?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
this text (an another text) "and a text" and again a text
```

What I want is to only match first `text`. Other two `text` words either is inside of parentheses or in quotes.

```
this text (an another text) "and a text" and again a text
      ^ this is I do want to capture.     and this -> ^
```

How can I do this in a single regex match? I cannot find any solution for both cases in a single match.

text can be in any order.

Comment: Do you mean [(?:\(.*\)|".*")|(text)](https://regex101.com/r/WEdHLh/1/) ?

Comment: Can they be in any order?

Comment: @Eric, yes they can be in any order.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness let me try that. .. Update: It selects all text regardless of what. Tried with regexr app.

Comment: Sorry, please click on the comment. I believe the escape of the brackets got lost due to formatting.

Comment: Can catch most but if the text is at the end, and is kind of ugly. Maybe someone can finish it https://regexr.com/3t4id

Comment: @Pratha the pattern is `(?:\(.*\)|".*")|(text)`

Comment: @UnbearableLightness you understand that "text" could be any text right? And that this could be in any order, right?

Comment: The question is not clear enough then. Also your solution below does not match `this -text-`., nor `'this-text'` nor `this@text@`

Comment: There are answers for [matching outside parenthesis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39565427) and [matching outside quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26609791) available already. You can combine them: [`text(?![^(]*\))(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)`](https://regex101.com/r/DwKrnw/1)

Answer (score 2):

```js
var sTest = 'this text (an another text) "and a text"';
document.writeln(sTest.replace(/\([^)]*text[^)]*\)|"[^"]*text[^"]*"|text/g, (sMatch)=>{ return (sMatch === 'text' ? 'TEXT' : sMatch); }));
```

Using [The Best Regex Trick](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html).
You define the things you do not want to include first, then the only one left is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it matches all possible combination. See result [here](https://regexr.com/3t4id)

```
 ((?!(?:( (\(|")[a-zA-Z ]+(\)|") )))?([\w ]+)(?=(?:( (\(|")[a-zA-Z ]+(\)|" ))))|([\w ]+$))
```

It could need some tuning but this is a good start I believe.

Comment: Don't know if this is a problem for the OP, but this regex would fail for something like `(an another text (text))` or `"some (text)"`

Answer (score 0):

I know you requested a *single regex*, but 2 passes is so much more extensible, easier to read and debug, and not less performant.

More *bookend types* can simply be added as well.

```js
const input = `this text (an another text) "and a text" more text

  ( this is
    text
   )
   
  " and more
    text"
    
 trailing text (should be the third text match)

`

// remove all matching (...) and "..."
const sanitized = input.replace(/\([^)]*\)|"[^"]*"/g, '')
console.log(sanitized)

// now match
let rx = /text/g
let m
let x = 0
while (m = rx.exec(sanitized)) {
  console.log(m)
}
```

Comment: I have to pass this regex to another method. Due to this it is not possible filter as you stated above. And I have no chance to access that part of code either :(

Comment: Could you pass a lamda to your other function instead of regex?